# Unable to restore a restore a MSSQL db from .bak file because of size unavailablity in disk

Tags: sql-server, restore

I need to restore a database from a .bak backup. When i tried it is showing insufficient disk space becuase the mdf and ldf files are also moving and in those ldf is aroud 100GB.
Is there a way to do it by omiting these files. Also when i checked i can see db restore can also be done by mdf files attaching is this same as normal database restore with all the tables and contents in place.

Comment: Why not just add more disk space, or restore to another a disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to restore a database from a .bak backup. When i tried it is showing insufficient disk space becuase the mdf and ldf files are also moving and in those ldf is aroud 100GB.

Correct, the `MDF` and `LDF` files **are** the database, which are stored in the backup file. The `MDF` is the data file for your database, that holds all the data in its current state. The `LDF` file is the Transaction Log file, which logs all the transactions that occurred in the database to put the `MDF` in it's current state, essentially.

> Is there a way to do it by omiting these files.

Nope, you need both to have a functioning database. It is not possible to even omit the Transaction Log file (`LDF`) and create a new one, when restoring from a backup. You'll need to increase the available space on the drive of where the database is being restored to, in order to restore that backup.

> Also when i checked i can see db restore can also be done by mdf files attaching

Yes, you can copy or move a database by only copying the `MDF` file and then [Attaching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) it to the SQL Server instance you want to move it to. (There's more steps to the process than that, but just speaking high level of what's possible.)

> is this same as normal database restore with all the tables and contents in place.

Not exactly. By leaving the `LDF` behind and using the `ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`, a new one will be created in its place. This is not necessarily a bad thing. But there is a timing risk of when you grab a copy of the `MDF` without the `LDF`, that it could be in an inconsistent state, if the database has uncommitted transactions, has not been `CHECKPOINT`ed, or was not shut down cleanly. Then when you attempt to attach the `MDF`, SQL Server will be unable to complete the `CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` operation, and will return the following error:

```
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.
Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Could not open new database 'YourDatabaseName'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
```